# javascript - substitute into a string template, but catch missing variables

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, mustache

I want to carry out variable substitutions on a string (I've already ruled out template literals because the string has to be stored and evaluated later).

Mustache or something like it would seem like a contender, but I want to know if the substitution was incomplete.  In this case, it's to produce urls, so missing parts mean invalid urls:

Testing this out in node:

```
var Mustache  = require('mustache');
var result = Mustache.render("/someurl/{{path1}}/{{path2}}/", {path1:"my-path-to-1"})
console.log(`result:${result}:`)
```

This happens without a problem, but the resulting url is useless because Mustache silently replaced the missing **path2** with an empty string.  What I would like to see is an exception getting thrown (best) or failing that an easy way to recognize that not everything was substituted.

Note:  the template string is arbitrary and so are the substitution object's contents.

output:

```
result:/someurl/my-path-to-1//:
```

This is the Python equivalent that I am looking for:

```
res = "/someurl/%(path1)s/%(path2)s/" % {"path1":"my-path-to-1"}
```

output:

```
KeyError: 'path2'
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using sprintf, which has the benefit of having a different format than Mustache (or Django) so that you can embed it in `data-url` or the like:

```
const sprintf = require("sprintf-js").sprintf;

var o_substit = {
  path1 : "mypath1"
};

var T_URL = "/someurl/%(path1)s/%(path2)s/";


console.log(`\nT_URL:${T_URL}, substitutions:`);
try {
  console.dir(o_substit);
  console.log("expecting a failure...")
  var url = sprintf(T_URL, o_substit);
  console.log(`  url:${url}:`);
}
catch (e){
  console.log(`  exception:${e}`);  
};

var o_substit = {
  path1 : "mypath1"
  ,path2 : "mypath2"
};


console.log(`\nT_URL:${T_URL}, substitutions:`);
try{
  console.dir(o_substit);
  console.log("\nexpecting a success:")
  var url = sprintf(T_URL, o_substit);
  console.log(`  url:${url}:`);
}
catch (e){
  console.log(`  exception:${e}`);  
};
```

output:

```
T_URL:/someurl/%(path1)s/%(path2)s/, substitutions:
{ path1: 'mypath1' }
expecting a failure...
  exception:Error: [sprintf] property 'path2' does not exist

T_URL:/someurl/%(path1)s/%(path2)s/, substitutions:
{ path1: 'mypath1', path2: 'mypath2' }

expecting a success:
  url:/someurl/mypath1/mypath2/:
```